# Javascript, change object value then call function inside Object.keys( ).forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to iterate over the Object of arrays given in the screenshot below.[image]

Then check with an if statement the third element (red marked) each time, and update it according to the if statements below.
After the conversion of the third element I need to call a function `calculateNormalizedProduct` passing as parameters the updated `Products[key]`, the problem is that when I `console.log` I still see the same values..What is the problem here in the way I have written this..?

```
var Products_Norm={}

Object.keys(Products).forEach(function (key) {

if (Products[key][2]==2){
    Products[key][2]=2

}
else if (Products[key][2]==24) {
    Products[key][2]=3

}
else if (Products[key][2]==720){
    Products[key][2]=15

}
else {
    Products[key][2]=0
}
console.log('before normalization and after convertion',Products[key],'Products[key][2]',Products[key][2])


Products_Norm[key]=calculateNormalizedProduct(Products[key],options)

console.log('after called normalization',Products_Norm[key])
})
```

An example is when the input (the array of the object) is

```
[30,9,24,0,9,9,price:339]
```

the output should be

```
[30,9,3,0,9,9,price:339]
```

On the updated array call the function `calculateNormalizedProduct`.
This should be done along all the arrays of the Object and save the results in the `Products_Norm`

I will slightly change the goal of the output in saving the values of the Products Object in a new Object `convertedProduct` so that let's assume the 
`Products[key]` is `[30,9,24,0,9,9,price:339]`
the 
`convertedProduct[key]=[30,9,3,0,9,9,price:339]`

So almost identical Objects apart from the third element.

Comment: share your product list object

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with example input and expected output

Comment: What does `calculateNormalizedProduct() function do ` It takes updated `Products object` and save it into `Products_Norm` ?

Comment: @jobayersozib the function uses as parameters the updated `Products` object. It calculates the normalized vector of the updated object and then return it back to`Products_Norm`

Comment: ok check my answer i'm not sure it meets your requirement .if you can please share you 
`calculateNormalizedProduct function snippet`

Comment: what if instead of the same Object I need to save the aforementioned results in a new Object `convertedProduct `?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your current object with arrays then you could do the following

Also there is no point in your first if statement since the value doesn't change

```
if (Products[key][2]==2){
    Products[key][2]=2

}
```

```js
const Products = {
  arr1: [30, 9, 24, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  arr2: [30, 9, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  arr3: [30, 9, 24, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  arr4: [30, 9, 720, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  arr5: [30, 9, 720, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}

console.log('products before', Products);
Object.keys(Products).forEach((key) => {
  if (Products[key][2] == 24) {
    Products[key][2] = 3

  } else if (Products[key][2] == 720) {
    Products[key][2] = 15

  } else {
    Products[key][2] = 0
  }
  // call your function calculateNormalizedProduct 
})

console.log('products after', Products);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...in` to iterate the object and then use `map`

```js
// iterate the object 
for (let keys in arr) {
  // cheekc if the value is an array
  if (Array.isArray(arr[keys]) {
      // use map to return new array of element
      arr[keys] = arr.keys.map((item, index) => {
        // if index === 2 mean third element
        if (index === 2) {
          // check if 2 then return 2
          if (item === 2) {
            return 2
          } else if (item === 24) {
            return 3;
          } else if (item === 720) {
            return 15
          }

        } else {
          // index is other than 2 return original element
          return item;
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

```html
if (Products[key][2]==2){ Products[key][2]=2 } else if (Products[key][2]==24) { Products[key][2]=3 } else if (Products[key][2]==720){ Products[key][2]=15 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Products=[
  [30,9,24,0,9,9,{price:339}],
  [30,9,2,0,9,9,{price:339}],
  [30,9,15,0,9,9,{price:339}],
  [30,9,24,0,9,9,{price:339}],
  [30,9,720,0,9,9,{price:339}],
]

var Products_Norm={}

function calculateNormalizedProduct(product){
  return product
}
Object.keys(Products).forEach(function (key) {

if (Products[key][2]==2){
    Products[key][2]=2

}
else if (Products[key][2]==24) {
    Products[key][2]=3

}
else if (Products[key][2]==720){
    Products[key][2]=15

}
else {
    Products[key][2]=0
}
//console.log('before normalization and after convertion',Products[key],'Products[key][2]',Products[key][2])


Products_Norm[key]=calculateNormalizedProduct(Products[key],'')

//console.log('after called normalization',Products)
})


console.log('after called normalization',Products_Norm)
```